# Application size and data usage

Tags: ios, iphone

How do I, from the iOS SDK, find out how much data an app is using.

By app data I mean the files that it stores, not the binary itself. For instance a lot of apps cache a load of data for offline use, is there a way to see how much disk space is being used per app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every app runs in its own sandbox, no files other than the ones in that sandbox can be created by that application. You could thus calculate the size of the sandbox folder, though I don't see a solution if you haven't yet jailbroken your iDevice.

E.g.:

```
$ cd /var/mobile/Applications/(app-code-here)
$ du -h .
```

Mind that the above code also calculates the size of the a application bundle itself.